# AngularJs e CSS table striped in dinamic grid

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I would like to know in this situation, how to leave a table-striped where I have a group and a sub-group

the result is that some lines are duplicating the color, I would like to know how can I solve this problem?

html

```
<tbody ng-repeat="a in group">
<tr ng-class-odd="'striped'">
<td>{{a.Name}}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in records" ng-class-odd="'striped'">
  <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
  <td>{{x.Country}}</td>  
</tr>
</tbody>
```

script:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    {
      "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "Country" : "Germany"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "Country" : "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "Country" : "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
      "Country" : "Austria"
    }
  ],
  $scope.group = [
    {
      "Name" : "A"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "B"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "C"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "D"
    }
  ]
});
```

[image for results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lryVp.png)

- ng-style: Created a function in the controller receiving $index and $parent.$index but for some reason it duplicated and repeated the loop.
- tbody tr:nth-child(even): duplicating the color;
- tbody tr:nth-child(odd): duplicating the color;
- $first%2 === 0 , $last%2 === 0 , $even , $odd.
  unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

ngRepeat creates a new scope anytime it is used. You are looking for the `$even` or `$odd` of the parent repeater when applying a `striped` class to the row. You can do this by using `$parent` in the attributes of `<tr>` or anywhere inside.
Something like this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="a in group">
    <!-- Always first, so always odd -->
    <tr class="striped">
        <td>{{a.Name}}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- offset by static row above, so invert to use even -->
    <tr ng-repeat="x in records" ng-class="{'striped':$parent.$even}">
        <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{x.Country}}</td>  
    </tr>
</tbody>
```